# How to test this statement using jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In our code, I have two statements

```
const { column, showTooltip, tooltipValue, data } = props;
const key = column.bindProperties[0].properties[0].name;
```

on testing, this gives error as

> "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined."

what is the meaning of this statement `column.bindProperties[0].properties[0].name;` and how to test it.

Comment: plz, could you show more code?

Comment: You are trying to access a deeply nested property here, traversing multiple layers of nested objects and arrays. If you need to verify that the chosen path actually exists, I'd use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which seems to be supported reasonably well nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can't guarantee that objects have certain properties.

When you try to access `column.bindProperties[0].properties[0].name`, either `column.bindProperties` or `column.bindProperties[0].properties` is `undefined` - hence the error you're getting.

You can either use [`lodash`'s `_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) or validate the keys are defined using the redundantly annoying:

```
const key = column
  && column.bindProperties
  && column.bindProperties[0]
  && column.bindProperties[0].properties
  && column.bindProperties[0].properties[0]
  && column.bindProperties[0].properties[0].name;
```

This will make sure your code won't break. If one expression in the chain isn't defined, the expression will stop evaluating and you'll just get `undefined` as the result.

Comment: The type of column is any. And I am just passing a number during the test .

Comment: Then you're not passing it correctly. Try debugging your code or printing `column`, so you'll find where the error is

Comment: what is "bindProperties"? is it just a property of column object or any method?

Comment: If you call `bindProperties[0]`, it should be an array

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has really just spelt it out, here's an example of optional chaining:

```
const key = column?.bindProperties?.[0]?.properties?.[0]?.name;
```

and with nullish coalescing:

```
const key = column?.bindProperties?.[0]?.properties?.[0]?.name ?? "I'm a fallback value";
```